# Pytest error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run pytest for my repository. The directory structure is as shown below. The command is ran at the root using `pytest -v tests`

```bash
.
├── project
│   ├── app.py
│   └── config_demo.json
└── tests
    └── unit_tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_app.py
```

It gave me the error message:

```bash
tests/unit_tests/test_app.py:3: in <module>
    from app import app
project/app.py:4: in <module>
    with open("config_demo.json", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
E   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config_demo.json'
```

The following are what each script contain (unnecessary portions removed).

`project/app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask


with open("config_demo.json", 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    base_config = json.load(f)

app = Flask(__name__)

# Healthcheck
@app.route('/healthcheck', methods=['GET'])
def healthcheck():
    return {"status": "ok"}, 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5002)
```

`project/config.json`

```json
{
    "sample":0
}
```

`tests/__init__.py`

```py
import sys
from os.path import dirname, join, normpath

THIS_DIR = dirname(__file__)
PROJ_DIR = normpath(join(THIS_DIR, '..', '..', 'project'))
sys.path.append(PROJ_DIR)
```

`tests/test_app.py`

```py
import pytest

from app import app


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def client():
    app_ = app.test_client()
    yield app_


def test_api_healthcheck_200(client):
    """test health check response 200"""
    response = client.get('/healthcheck')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json['status'] == 'ok'
```

It seems like some path issues, what could be wrong?

Based on suggestions online & colleagues, we tried adding `pytest.ini` to the test folder, but it gave the same error.

Pardon, its my first time writing pytest, but I couldn't find anything else that can resolve this pathing problem.